# WPF. Radiobutton как снять выбор при повторном нажатии?

Tags: c#, wpf

Надо, чтоб при повторном нажатии выбор снимался. Помогите плиз!
Пробывал так, вообще не клацается...

```
private void Profnav_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (Profnav.IsChecked)
            {
                case true:
                    Profnav.IsChecked = false;
                    break;
                case false:
                    Profnav.IsChecked = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну например так:

```
<ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Grid>
                <RadioButton IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Border Background="Transparent"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ToggleButton.Template>
</ToggleButton>
```

Пояснение: вы реально хотите поведение как у `ToggleButton`, но чтобы выглядело как `RadioButton`. Окей, сделаем `ToggleButton`, а шаблоном положим `RadioButton`. Если просто положить `RadioButton`, то на клике она будет себя выделять всегда, поэтому положим сверху прозрачный по цвету, но непрозрачный для кликов `Border`. Всё.

---

Если вам нужно много таких штук, определите стиль:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ToggleButton" x:Key="RadioLookToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Grid>
                        <RadioButton IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                     VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Border Background="Transparent"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

```
<ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource RadioLookToggleButton}"/>
```

Comment: Да, то, что надо! Спасибо!

Comment: @Awesome7997: Пожалуйста :)

Comment: @Awesome7997: Добавил `HorizontalAlignment` и `VerticalAlignment` в разметку.